# I want to get user id in a get function

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
 Future<String> getCurrentUser() async {
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
    final uid = user.uid;
    return uid;
  }
```

**I want to have user uid in the document but I cant get it .**

```
 Stream<List<RezervasyonListesi>> get rezervasonlarlistesi1 {
   return rezervasyonCollectionRef
       .document() // **In document I want refer to user uid ;**
       .collection("rezerve")
       .snapshots()
       .map(_rezervasyonlistesifromsnap);
 }
```

I tried this but didnt work

```
  Stream<List<RezervasyonListesi>> get rezervasonlarlistesi {
    getCurrentUser().then((value) {
      return rezervasyonCollectionRef
          .document(value)
          .collection("rezerve")
          .snapshots()
          .map(_rezervasyonlistesifromsnap);
    });
    
  }
```

Stream<List< RezervasyonListesi>> is not a type of future because of that I cant use async in that function .Without ascyn how can I get my firebase user uid.

**class of RezervasyonListesi**

```
class RezervasyonListesi {
  final String name;
  final String address;
  final String image;
  final String rating;
  final String description;
  RezervasyonListesi(
      {this.address, this.description, this.image, this.name, this.rating});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
Stream<List<RezervasyonListesi>> get rezervasonlarlistesi async*{
 String currentUser = await getCurrentUser();
 yield* rezervasyonCollectionRef.document(currentUser.uid).snapshots().map((snapshot){
    return snapshot.data;
 });
}
```

Comment: The getter 'snapshot' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentSnapshot'.
Try importing the library that defines 'snapshot', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'snapshot'.dartundefined_getter

Comment: this time saying that :)))   The getter 'value' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentSnapshot'.
Try importing the library that defines 'value', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.dartundefined_getter

Comment: try `.data` or `.data()`

Comment: withoud ()   - >The return type 'Map<String, dynamic>' isn't a 'List<RezervasyonListesi>', as required by the closure's context.dartreturn_of_invalid_type_from_closure

Comment: with data() -> The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220929/discussion-between-fatihmrcn-and-locked).